# Missing PHPUnit in PhpStorm settings on Windows

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm community addition and the settings menu doesn't show the PHPUnit entry like it should (all the manuals that I encountered in the web show it).

You can see that my PHP entry is missing the PHPUnit:

[image]

From the command line I have installed PHPUnit successfully:

[image]

Any ideas what is broken? Is it the fact that I'm using the community edition (phpstorm-2018.3)?

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking at the right place.

Per [PHPStorm's documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-phpunit-framework.html#php_test_frameworks_phpunit_integrate),

> In the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), expand the Languages
>   and Frameworks node and select Test Frameworks under PHP.

Full settings path: `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Test Frameworks`.